# How to insert font-awesome's span glyphicons inside cakephp2.8 link function,

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

Basically, I am trying to output this.

```
<a href="/users/info"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span>My Bookings <b></b></a>
```

But, [Html->link( ... )](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper::link)  does not allow for this to happen easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if there is nothing in `<b>` tag than

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link('My booking'.'<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt">'.'</span>'.'<b>'.'</b>',
                                                                                array
                                                                                (
                                                                                    'controller'=>'user',
                                                                                    'action'=>'info',
                                                                                ),
                                                                                array
                                                                                (
                                                                                    'escape'=>false  
                                                                                )
                                                                            );?>
```